# ASP.NET Core web api with Entity framework core not working with MySQL on ubuntu

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working with ASP.NET core on linux (ubuntu 16.04) and I'm trying to connect entity framework core with MySQL.
At first, I used EF without external database (I don't understand much but, I think there's an internal DB that EF use by default) and all http methods (get, post, put ...) worked.

then I connected EF with MySQL using Pomelo, this is my **NuGet.config** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Pomelo" value="https://www.myget.org/F/pomelo/api/v3/index.json"/>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" />
  </packageSources>
 </configuration>
```

and this is my **startup.cs** file :
`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using test.Context;
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 


namespace test
{
   public class Startup
   {
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
        Configuration = configuration;
      }

      public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
        services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
                    builder => {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ValuesContext>(opt => 
                    opt.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=pfe2018"));
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
}
```

`

Then, I tested the project with a simple console code in **program.cs** and it worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using test.Context;
using test.Models;

namespace test
{
   public class Program
   {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        using (var context = new ValuesContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            // Creating a new Value and saving it to the database                
            context.values.Add(new Values {
                fname = "abc",
                lname = "efg",
                age = 100
            });
            var count = context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} records saved to database", count);

            // Retrieving and displaying data
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("All Values in the database:");
            foreach (var value in context.values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{2}  |{0} | {1}", value.fname, value.lname, value.id);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
  }
}
```

the new value was successfuly added to the database, so I thought I just have to run the WEB API by changing the code in the main() method in **Program.cs** :

```
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            string url = "http://localhost:5000";
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(url)
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
```

My DbContext and Controller are as follows :

**ValuesContext** :

```
     using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        using test.Models;

        namespace test.Context
        {
            public class ValuesContext : DbContext
            {
                public ValuesContext(DbContextOptions<ValuesContext> options) : base(options) { }
                public ValuesContext() {}
                public DbSet<Values> values { get; set; }
                protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) =>         
optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=pfe2018");
                    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
                        modelBuilder.Entity<Values>(entity => {
                            entity.HasKey(v => v.id).HasName("VALUE_ID");
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

**ValuesController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using test.Context;
using test.Models;

namespace test.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller {

        private readonly ValuesContext _context;

        public ValuesController(ValuesContext context) {
            _context = context;
            _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Values> GetAll()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_context.values.ToList());
            return _context.values.ToList();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Values value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _context.values.Add(value);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return new CreatedAtRouteResult("itemRoute", new {id = value.id} , value);
        }
    }
}
```

when I try GET method with cURL :

> curl -I http://localhost:5000/api/values

this is the response status :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 22 Feb 2018 16:46:07 GMT
Server: Kestrel
```

any suggestion would be helpfull.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a logger to see what is happening when you send a request

Comment: if it's possible could you give me a hint how to do it ? knowing that I'm working with windows but connected to a remote Ubuntu server using putty

Comment: The default template for dotnet core apps write logs to the console by default . You can also configure it to write to a file. See this for instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x or you can use another library such as https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging

Comment: The fact that you're getting an error 404  (and not an error 500) probably means there's something weird with your routing, that has nothing to do with EF.

Comment: Well first thing in the morning, the GET request is returning 500 status code now. Nothing wrong with my routing since when i remove Mysql as DbServiceProvider and use InMemoryDatabase instead, the API works and I receive 200 ok status.